# Put column sums in a new row in a matrix

Tags: r, sum, col

I have a data frame that consists of municipality names (factors) in the first column and number of projects (integers) in columns two and three.

```
Var.1<-c("Andover", "Avon", "Bethany")
Freq.x<-c(2,NA,10)
Freq.y<-c(4,2,9)
Projects<-data.frame(Var.1,as.integer(as.numeric(Freq.y)),as.integer(as.numeric(Freq.x)))
```

[Note: I am making the second and third columns as integers here because that's how they are categorized in my actual data set.]

I was able to take the row sums of the rows using:

```
Projects$Sum<-rowSums(Projects[,2:3])
```

However, I'm unable to figure out how to take the column sums. I tried using the following formula:

```
Projects[Total,]<-colSums(Projects[2:3,])
```

I get the error:

> Error in colSums(Projects[2:3, ]) : 'x' must be numeric

Even when I convert the second and third columns to `as.numeric`, I get the same response.

Can someone advise how to obtain the column sums create a new row at the bottom which will house the results?

Comment: It should be `colSums(Projects[,2:3])`  In your code, it was subsetting the 2nd 3rd rows of all the columns of which the first column is not numeric.

Comment: I suggest to use something like `rbind(Projects, colSums(Projects))`.  However, it is not that simple:
a) first column is not numeric;
b) first column is a factor and cannot easily take arbitrary values.

Comment: @akrun What you suggested provides the sum of each column. However, I want to embed that at the bottom of the Projects dataframe so that there is a fourth row containing the column sums. How would I do that?

Comment: @Ott Toomet I recognize that I cannot use the function you provided because the first column is not numeric. Given that in this table some columns are factors and others are numbers, how can I take the column sums of the numbers?

Comment: @Danny If you can make the first column as row.names and the 'Projects` as `matrix, we can use `addmargins`

Comment: @akrun, thank you for the prompt response. I am still very new to R. Could you be more explicit with how to do what you suggest?

Comment: i.e. `addmargins('row.names<-'(as.matrix(Projects[2:3]), Projects[,1]),1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Var.1<-c("Andover", "Avon", "Bethany")
Freq.x<-c(2,NA,10)
Freq.y<-c(4,2,9)
freq <- cbind(Freq.x, Freq.y)
freq <- rbind(freq, colSums(freq, na.rm=TRUE))
Projects <- data.frame(name=c(Var.1, "Total"), freq)
```

In particular: keep numeric part separate and compute it's sums; add "TOtal" to the character vector before it will be converted to factor, and thereafter make the data.frame